# Не получается прикрутить графики

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно научиться строить графики. Для этого я загуглил несколько библиотек и выбрал из найденных то, что мне показалось проще: [uvharts](http://imaginea.github.io/uvCharts/index.html). В javascript я практически не разбираюсь. По логике должно всё отображаться. Но по факту ничего. В качестве справочной документации использовал документы на сайте [uvcharts](https://github.com/Imaginea/uvCharts/blob/master/readme/uvcharts_quick_start_guide.md). После того, как у меня ничего не прикрутилось, решил чуть погуглить примеров. Нашёл [вот это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmsQjVleNPo). Здесь всё то же самое. Но зачем-то берутся библиотеки с [d3js.org](https://d3js.org/). Окей, взял и их. Но ничего не поменялось. В итоге, имею следующий код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = 'vendor/d3/d3.min.js'></script>
        <script src = 'vendor/uvcharts-1.1.0/uvcharts.min.js'></script>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            var init  = function () {
                var graphdef = {
                    categories: ['uvCharts'];
                    dataset: { 
                        'uvCharts': [
                            {name: '2009', value: 67},
                            {name: '2010', value: 97},
                            {name: '2011', value: 120},
                            {name: '2012', value: 167},
                            {name: '2013', value: 234}
                        ]
                    }
                }
                var chartObject = uv.chart('Bar', graphdef);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = 'init()'>
        <div id = 'uv-div'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Все скрипты в папке `vendor` имеются:

[image: d3]
[image: uvcharts]

В связи с этим имею вопросы:

- Не понимаю, отчего не происходит визуализация графика.
- Для чего подключать библиотеку `d3js.org`?

Comment: А папке с index.html в папке `vendor` есть те скрипты, которые вы загружаете?

Comment: @gil9red, разумеется. Добавил скрины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: У вас синтаксические ошибки в коде

2: Uvcharts  новыми версиями d3 (4.*) работать отказывается, у меня завелось, когда я подключил [3.2.2](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js)

Вот так всё завелось:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
        <script src = 'http://imaginea.github.io/uvCharts/js/uvcharts.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'uv-div'></div>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            var graphdef = {
                categories: ['uvCharts'],
                dataset: {
                    'uvCharts': [
                        {name: '2009', value: 67},
                        {name: '2010', value: 97},
                        {name: '2011', value: 120},
                        {name: '2012', value: 167},
                        {name: '2013', value: 234}
                    ]
                }
            }
            uv.chart('Bar', graphdef);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```